# Contour integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xdx}{(x-1)^{4}-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm having a little trouble solving this contour integral. I've found the singularities to be at 0, 2, and $1\pm i$. I'm not quite sure how to evaluate the integral when there are two poles on the contour instead of just one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Calculate the residues ... Cauchy's Residue theorem etc...

Comment: Maybe, you're asking for the $\textit{Principal Value}$.

Comment: @JohnPage Just to clarify there is an $x$ in the numerator  ? ... and the in denominator, that will cancel so your integral can be rewritten as
$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x-2)(x^2-2x+2)}$
So there is only one singularity on the contour.

Comment: There is a subtle but important difference between $\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x}=0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x}$, that simply does not exist. The same applies to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Assuming the question asks for the *Principal Value* $\pars{~\mrm{P.V.}~}$:

\begin{align}
&\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x\,\dd x \over \pars{x - 1}^{4} - 1}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{def.}}{=} &\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}{x\,\dd x \over \pars{x - 1}^{4} - 1} +
\int_{\epsilon}^{2 - \epsilon}{x\,\dd x \over \pars{x - 1}^{4} - 1} +
\int_{2 + \epsilon}^{\infty}{x\,\dd x \over \pars{x - 1}^{4} - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{-\infty}^{-1 - \epsilon}{x + 1 \over x^{4} - 1}\,\dd x +
\int_{-1 + \epsilon}^{1 - \epsilon}{x + 1 \over x^{4} - 1}\,\dd x +
\int_{1 + \epsilon}^{\infty}{x + 1 \over x^{4} - 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{-\infty}^{-1 - \epsilon}{\dd x \over \pars{x - 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x +
2\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{\dd x \over x^{4} - 1} -
\int_{0}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}{x \over \pars{x - 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x}
\\[1cm] = &\
-\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}
\\[5mm] + &\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\braces{%
\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}\bracks{%
{2 \over x^{4} - 1} - {x \over \pars{x - 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}}\,\dd x -
\int_{1 - \epsilon}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}
{x \over \pars{x - 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x}
\\[1cm] & =
-\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}} -
\int_{0}^{1}{x + 2 \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] - & \ \underbrace{%
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{1 - \epsilon}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}
{x \over \pars{x - 1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x}_{\ds{=\ 0}} =
\bbx{-\ds{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}

> I left to you the integral evaluations and the limit evaluation.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I checked it with $\texttt{Mathematica}$.
$$
\texttt{Integrate[x/((x - 1)^4 - 1), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]}
$$

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I previously simplified $\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$ as $\frac{1}{x+1}$ instead of $\frac{1}{x-1}$, now fixed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It still works: $-\pi/2$. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, sure, you are right. It was me not double-checking my computations. (+1) to you.

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{(x-1)^4-1}\,dx = \text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x+1}{x^4-1}\,dx = \text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x-1)(x^2+1)} $$
equals, by partial fraction decomposition,
$$ \frac{1}{2}\,\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x-1}-\frac{1}{2}\,\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}\,dx = \color{red}{-\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

Comment: Ah, good use shifting the integral and PFD.